# Ignite crashed at start on Windows Server 12

Tags: windows, out-of-memory, ignite

Apache Ignite 2.1.0 crashed at start on Windows Server 12 with default-config.xml.

Important of Log:

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 x86

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 25.131-b11

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM total memory: 0.96GB

…

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+AggressiveOpts, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m, -DIGNITE_QUIET=true, -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=C:\Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin\work\ignite_success_d782cfc3-3908-4f42-90c8-33e4eb440de7, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49117, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -DIGNITE_HOME=C:\Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin, -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=ignite.bat]

[11:08:16,455][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] System cache's MemoryPolicy size is configured to 40 MB. Use MemoryConfiguration.systemCacheMemorySize property to change the setting.

[11:08:16,471][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' memoryPolicy: ['ignite-sys-cache']]

…

[11:08:18,846][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#30%null%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Failed to reinitialize local partitions (preloading will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=0], nodeId=d7ac488c, evt=NODE_JOINED]

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.allocateMemory(GridUnsafe.java:1054)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.mem.unsafe.UnsafeMemoryProvider.nextRegion(UnsafeMemoryProvider.java:80)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.addSegment(PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.java:610)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.start(PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.startMemoryPolicies(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.onActivate(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:949)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedContext.activate(GridCacheSharedContext.java:244)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:602)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1901)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is resolved with a snippet in the configuration file

```
    <property name="memoryConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.MemoryConfiguration">
            <!-- Setting a name of the default memory policy -->
            <property name="defaultMemoryPolicyName" value="Default_Region"/>
            <!-- Setting the page size to 4 KB -->
            <property name="pageSize" value="4096"/>
            <property name="systemCacheInitialSize" value="#{40 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
            <property name="systemCacheMaxSize" value="#{40 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

            <!-- Defining several memory policies for different memory regions -->
            <property name="memoryPolicies">
                <list>
                    <!--
                        Default memory region that grows endlessly. A cache is bound to this memory region
                        unless it sets another one in its CacheConfiguration.
                    -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.MemoryPolicyConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!-- 100 MB memory region with disabled eviction -->
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{20 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{20 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    </bean>

                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: Which part of that configuration solved your problem?